# SQL flags / IF statements / new column linking common column values

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, sql-server-2014, multiple-tables

I have multiple (8) tables that all have a column called `Encounter_ID`. The same `Encounter_ID` can appear in one or multiple tables. The end goal is to see which tables a specific `Encounter_ID` appears in.

I would like to create columns called `Table1_Flag`, `Table2_Flag` etc., with a value of 'Y' or 'N'. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and then importing the code into a presentation layer software that allows users to select a specific encounter with the goal to see which table it falls under.

I am a nurse working in an IT dept. so I have basic SQL coding experience and would appreciate any help.

**Table 1**

```
Encounter_ID
1
2
3
4
5
8
9
11
```

**Table 2**

```
Encounter_ID
2
3
5
6
7
11
13
```

**Table 3**

```
Encounter_ID
1
3
5
6
10
12
13
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select * 
from (
    select 'table1' tablename, encounter_id from table1 union all
    select 'table2' tablename, encounter_id from table2 union all
    select 'table3' tablename, encounter_id from table3
) t
where encounter_id = 10;
```

http://rextester.com/LGQZ72769

Comment: Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 18
No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'. 

Getting this error when running the query

Comment: I am not sure why this error is coming. I've added a working demo in the answer. Can you provide me with the exact query you are running?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Encounter_ID,
CASE WHEN t1.encounter_ID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END as Table1_Flag,
CASE WHEN t2.encounter_ID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END as Table2_Flag,
CASE WHEN t3.encounter_ID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END as Table3_Flag
FROM
(SELECT Encounter_ID FROM Table1 union all
 SELECT Encounter_ID FROM Table2 union all
 SELECT Encounter_ID FROM Table3) t
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t.Encounter_ID = t1.Encounter_ID
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 ON t.Encounter_ID = t2.Encounter_ID
LEFT JOIN Table1 t3 ON t.Encounter_ID = t3.Encounter_ID
ORDER BY t.encounter_id
```

Here is a working example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/516dbc/7/0